# set height of div(s) at fullscreen with a scrollbar in the div and a header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to put together a quick viewer for data.  I need 3 cells... a header, and two columns (I'm using Bootstrap).  I'd like the two columns to scroll independently of each other. I'll be populating the left column with vertical data and when an item is selected, I'll use that to populate the right column with more vertical data...

I won't always know the height of the header either.  I'm working with this right now:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height {height: 100%;}
```

and

```
<div class='container-fluid full-height'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12' id='headerContent'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row full-height'>
        <div class='col-md-6 full-height' id='events'></div>
        <div class='col-md-6 full-height' id='archive'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the closest I've been able to get so far.  When I do this, my columns are 100% of the height of the container (not taking the header in to account) and hang slightly longer than the screen.

**I'm trying to work with flexbox right now, but it's causing some other funkiness that I don't like... adding flexbox made the header div suddenly get slightly smaller to the point that it's data is overflowing (I don't want that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use flexbox, you can use some simple jquery to get the correct heights

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12' id='headerContent'>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row full-height'>
        <div class='col-md-6 full-height' id='events'></div>
        <div class='col-md-6 full-height' id='archive'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#headerContent { 
    background-color: red;
    height: 45px;
}

.full-height {height: 100%; background-color: #ddd; }

.col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#archive {
    background-color: #666;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
        var full_height = $('body').height() - $('#headerContent').height();
        $('.full-height').height(full_height);
    });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azuh6fb2/

Comment: This worked.  I had tried doing this already, but it didn't work so I thought I must be doing something else wrong.  After your sample worked, I revisited what I had done and found my problem... I was calling my resize function at the end of my document.ready... But that happens before the finish of the JSON call to get data to populate the header.  ASYNCH strikes again!  Thanks for making me go back and re-look at what I was screwing up!

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the js async , you can use deferred or promise with jQuery to execute the full_height function that karanmhatre said to you.

http://api.jquery.com/?s=promise

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred

Good luck!